# How I get the value from the Immediate part of a 32 Bit sequence in C?

Tags: c, stack, opcode, vm-implementation

I built a virtual machine in C. And for this I have the Instruction

```
pushc <const>
```

I saved the command and the value in 32 Bit. The First 8 Bit are for the command and the rest for the value.

**8 Bit -> Opcode**
**24 Bit -> Immediate value**

For this I make a macro

```
#define PUSHC 1 //1 is for the command value in the Opcode
#define IMMEDIATE(x) ((x) & 0x00FFFFFF)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
**#define SIGN_EXTEND(i) ((i) & 0x00800000 ? (i) | 0xFF000000 : (i))**
```

Then I load for testing this in a unsigned int array:

**Update:**

```
unsigned int code[] = { (PUSHC << 24 | IMMEDIATE(2)),
                        (PUSHC << 24 | SIGN_EXTEND(-2)),
                         ...};
```

later in my code I want to get the Immediate value of the pushc command and push this value to a stack...

I get every Instruction (IR) from the array and built my stack.

**UPDATE:**

```
 void exec(unsigned int IR){

      unsigned int opcode = (IR >> 24) & 0xff;
      unsigned int imm = (IR & 0xffffff);

     switch(opcode){
       case PUSHC: {
         stack[sp] = imm;
         sp = sp + 1;
         break;
}
}

    ...

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a bitwise `AND` to mask out the lower 24 bits, then use it in the `case`:

```
const uint8_t opcode = (IR >> 24) & 0xff;
const uint32_t imm = (IR & 0xffffff);
switch(opcode)
{
  case PUSHC:
    stack[sp] = imm;
    break;
}
```

I shifted around the extraction of the opcode to make the `case` easier to read.

Comment: what is the value? i dont understand

Comment: @Tarasov Sorry, got fooled by your code. :) Now extracts both parts from `IR`.

Comment: thanks it work...you show me a better way...I want to make 2^24 and calculate them..but your way is better :D but you know what is with negative values how -2 or -3 ? :/

Comment: @Tarasov You're going to have to work a bit to get negative values to work, you need to decide if the immediate is signed or unsigned. If it's signed, you need to sign-extend the top bit (basically copy bit 23 into bits 24..31).

Comment: look @ my update ..how i can push negative values... :(