# How to fix: OP-code isn't read out correctly

Tags: c, c89, opcode, vm-implementation

I'm currently trying to write a Ninja VM, a task which was given to me as an exercise. Opcode and value are saved in a 32-Bit unsigned int, with the first 8 bit being the opcode and the rest being the value. To deal with a negative value, I use a macro given to me with the exercise

`#define SIGN_EXTEND(i) ((i) & 0x00800000 ? (i) | 0xFF000000 : (i))`

However, when trying to retrieve the op-code of

`unsigned int i = (PUSHC << 24) | SIGN_EXTEND(-2);` (where `PUSHC` equals `1`)

by using a bit-wise `AND` as seen here ->

`int opcode = (i>>24)&0xff`

my result is `255`, although this extraction method works when the value is positive and reproduces the correct op-code in these cases.

While researching this, I found "[How I get the value from the Immediate part of a 32 Bit sequence in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387875/how-i-get-the-value-from-the-immediate-part-of-a-32-bit-sequence-in-c)", which seemingly deals with what I'm asking, however the answer given in that question is exactly what I'm doing, anyone know more?

Comment: This macro seem to be converting from *24*-bit negative values to *32*-bit. So `SIGN_EXTEND(-2)` is using it not as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIGN_EXTEND` looks like it is intended to be used in decoding, to take the 24 bits that have been extracted from the instruction and convert them to a 32-bit signed integer. It looks like it is not intended to be used in encoding. For encoding, `IMMEDIATE(x)` appears to be intended for that. Given a 32-bit signed integer, it produces a 24-bit signed integer, providing the value fits.

So:

```
unsigned int i = (PUSHC << 24) | SIGN_EXTEND(-2);
```

should be:

```
unsigned int i = (PUSHC << 24) | IMMEDIATE(-2);
```

Comment: Thank you, that did indeed fix my problem. I tried to research the way the macros work beforehand, but it appears I haven't really grasped them yet. I'd be grateful if anyone could explain what exactly happens when you enter a value into them.

`#define IMMEDIATE(x) ((x) & 0x00FFFFFF)`

&

`#define SIGN_EXTEND(i) ((i) & 0x00800000 ? (i) | 0xFF000000 : (i))`